# LSP4E connected to Xtext Language Server does not show errors in the editor

Tags: eclipse, xtext

Currently I'm testing a Xtext grammar by using the Language Server configuration specified in the Xtext documentation (see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/340_lsp_support.html)). As I understand from that documentation, the text editor should be able to

> explore the supported language features like syntax highlighting,
> content assist, validation, displaying code lenses, quickfixes,
> formatting

However on my side the editor just shows some things as code completion but does not show validation errors (e.g. underlining the problems). Moreover the "Problems" view appears empty even though the language server communication log correctly shows the validation errors being sent to the client.

Is there something more to be done on the Eclipse configuration (specific to lsp4e) which may be overlooked in the Xtext documentation for Language Server?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

As stated on the comments the versions used are the following:

On one side the language server using Xtext version `2.27.0` which works with `lsp4j 0.14.0.v20220526-1518`.
On the other side (as client) Eclipse IDE using `lsp4e 0.13.13.202207281726` and `lsp4j 0.14.0.v20220526-1518`

I've been able to debug lsp4e in the scenario and it seems to fail because the call to:

```
@Override
public final void publishDiagnostics(PublishDiagnosticsParams diagnostics) {
    diagnosticConsumer.accept(diagnostics);
}
```

in `LanguageClientImpl` results in a NPE because of `diagnosticConsumer` being `null`.

By taking a look who initializes the `diagnosticConsumer` I see that it is only initialized if the `LanguageServerDefinition` being used is of type `ExtensionLanguageServerDefinition`. However in my scenario the `LanguageServerDefinition` used is of type `LaunchConfigurationLanguageServerDefinition` (which may be related with the fact that the Language Server configuration associates a `content-type` with a Java launch configuration).

Any ideas of what I could be missing?

**UPDATE 2**

I've opened an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/lsp4e/issues/239) where a discussion is ongoing.

Comment: did you make sure that the lsp4j versions in Xtext and LSP4e match. did you also check error logs?

Comment: Currently using Xtext version 2.27.0 which works with lsp4j 0.14.0. The version of LSP4e is 0.13.12. On the other side the Error Log window does not show errors.
The only thing I see in the LS console is a warning -> "org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint handleCancellation
WARNING: Unmatched cancel notification for request id 5"
It seems that the client sends cancellation requests to requests that were served already. Apart from that I cannot see any other error sign.

Comment: i mean the lsp4j version lsp4e uses. besides that you can debug lsp4j and see what it does with the publishDiagnostic notifications

Comment: Confirmed same versions. On one side the language server using Xtext version 2.27.0 which works with lsp4j 0.14.0.v20220526-1518. On the other side (as client) Eclipse IDE using lsp4e version 0.13.13.202207281726 and lsp4j 0.14.0.v20220526-1518 .

Comment: I've updated the question with my findings

Comment: have seen you have meanwhile created https://github.com/eclipse/lsp4e/issues/239 the problem is that lsp4e does not handle the launchh config based configurations again

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved [here](https://github.com/eclipse/lsp4e/issues/239). After using the patched version of LSP4E I'm able to see the errors on the UI.